# Why does changing the product operand order change the result of the expression when constants are involved?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to calculate the volume of a sphere given the radius as a user input.  Pi is defined as a constant in my program, and I am using the pow function.

For some reason, I get different results when I switch the order of the 4/3 and the PI.  Here is some code to further explain:

```
const double PI = 3.141593;

int main()
{
    double radius;
    double volume;
    cout << "Enter the radius of a sphere, and the volume will be given." << endl;
    cin >> radius;
    volume = 4 / 3 * PI * (pow(radius, 3));
    cout << "The volume of a sphere with radius " << radius << " is " << volume << endl;
}
```

The correct answer is only displayed when the constant is placed at the beginning of the expression.  For example, when 3 is entered as the radius, the answer is 84.823.  But when that expression is displayed like this:

```
volume = PI * 4 / 3 * (pow(radius, 3));
```

the answer is 113.097.  What is the reason for this?

Comment: Change that 4 to `4.0`, otherwise you are performing integer division.

Comment: Also, you don't need any input statements.  You could have a full program and eliminate more than half the code that you posted, [as this example shows](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64e923b02b4ef771).

Comment: FYI, if the 4 and 3 were integer variables, you could use `(double) a / (double) b` to force them to be treated as floating point.

Comment: Because division, multiplication, addition, and subtraction are all left-to-right associative and because of rules of type promotion. `4/3*PI` works by calculating `4/3` as a group (which gives an `int`,  i.e. `1` not `1.333...`) and the multiplication by `PI`  promotes the `1` to `double` before multiplying - so the overall result is `PI`.     Whereas `PI * 4 / 3`  computes `PI*4` as a group (promotes `4` to `double` and multiplies), giving a result of type `double` equal to `4.0*PI`.  `3` is promoted to `double` before dividing, and the overall result is equal to one and one-third times `PI`